# OSX 10.14 script compiled as stand-alone executable using pyinstall if script include import scipy.stats

Tags: macos, scipy, pyinstaller

Under Mac OSX 10.14 (but not under OS 10.12) stand-alone executables compiled with pyinstaller fail if the script includes "import scipy.stats" or "from scipy import stats"

python 2.7.15. pyinstaller 3.4 scipy 1.2.1
macOS 10.14.4

Scripts run fine using python interpreter, but when compiled as a one-file executable using pyinstaller -F scriptName.py pyinstaller succeeds, but when the executable is run I get the error below.

This does not happen under either Windows or Linux, and does not happen if I compile the script on an older laptop run OS10.12.6.

I have updated to the most recent version of both pyinstaller and scipy.

The rest of the code does not seem to matter.  Executable fails whenever scipy.stats is imported.

> import scipy.stat

s

or

> from scipy import stats
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/rthooks/pyi_rth_pkgres.py", line 11,
>   in    File
>   "lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py",
>   line 395, in load_module   File
>   "site-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py", line 959, in 
>   File "site-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py", line 963, in
>   Environment   File "site-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py", line
>   190, in get_supported_platform   File
>   "site-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py", line 395, in
>   get_build_platform   File "sysconfig.py", line 618, in get_platform
>   File "sysconfig.py", line 482, in get_config_vars   File
>   "sysconfig.py", line 365, in _init_posix ImportError: No module named
>   _sysconfigdata [18734] Failed to execute script pyi_rth_pkgres

`

Comment: Can you try doing `pyinstaller -F scriptName.py --hiddenimport _sysconfigdata`

Comment: Yes!  Worked perfectly.  I had tried hiddenimport but missed the underscore before sysconfigdata.  Thank you very much!

Comment: You're Wellcome! I went ahead and put the info in an answer in case others have a similar issue, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

When building with `pyinstaller` use:

```
pyinstaller -F scriptName.py --hiddenimport _sysconfigdata
```

**Reference**:

↳ https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/3198