# Errors while running Kivy after PyInstaller: pyi_rth_pkgres, wordcount.kv, unable to get a window etc

Tags: python, python-3.x, dependencies, kivy, pyinstaller

I need to compile a standalone executive or `--onedir` version of it for my Kivy application for Windows using PyInstaller. I experience problems one after another, and this is why I post it here. I can find solutions for almost all of them, but it seems that something goes wrong from the beginning.

The program consists of *.py* and *.kv* file, requires (apart from *Kivy* modules) only *Textract* (imported `as txt`)  and works perfectly if I use shell of IDLE.

I use the latest versions of *Kivy* and *PyInstaller* (in case if PyInstaller I also tried developer version, as [some people suggested](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/2137)).

The first problem I encounter is

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pkg_resources.py2_warn'
[4808] Failed to execute script pyi_rth_pkgres
```

which I solve with

```
pyinstaller wordcount.py --hiddenimport pkg_resources.py2_warn
```

as [some people suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56176438/osx-10-14-script-compiled-as-stand-alone-executable-using-pyinstall-if-script-inpyinstaller) to deal with this issue before. Then, full of pleasant expectations, I run the *.exe* again and get this:

```
 FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'wordcount.kv'
[3356] Failed to execute script wordcount
```

Obviously, the *.kv* was somehow not included in the package, okay, I change my command again:

```
pyinstaller wordcount.py --add-data "./wordcount.kv;." --hiddenimport pkg_resources.py2_warn
```

manually forcing the *.kv* into package. Or I could just copy it there - with the same result:

```
[WARNING] [Image       ] Unable to load image <C:\GUI Projects\wordcount\dist\wordcount\kivy_install\data\glsl\default.png>
[CRITICAL] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider. Please enable debug logging (e.g. add -d if running from the command line, or change the log level in the config) and re-run your app to identify potential causes
sdl2 - Exception: SDL2: Unable to load image
  File "site-packages\kivy\core\__init__.py", line 71, in core_select_lib
  File "site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 152, in __init__
  File "site-packages\kivy\core\window\__init__.py", line 981, in __init__
  File "site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 312, in create_window
  File "site-packages\kivy\core\window\__init__.py", line 1258, in create_window
  File "kivy\graphics\instructions.pyx", line 783, in kivy.graphics.instructions.RenderContext.__init__
  File "site-packages\kivy\core\image\__init__.py", line 561, in __init__
  File "site-packages\kivy\core\image\__init__.py", line 756, in _set_filename
  File "site-packages\kivy\core\image\__init__.py", line 460, in load
  File "site-packages\kivy\core\image\__init__.py", line 223, in __init__
  File "site-packages\kivy\core\image\img_sdl2.py", line 47, in load

[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.
```

[as people suggest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42671456/sdl2-error-unable-to-load-image-default-png-when-freezing-kivy-application), onw may just copy *.dll*s to the directory ([Dist]\\libpng16-16.dll). Or to rewrite *spec.* like this:
[image]

... regrettably, without any positive result.

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "wordcount.py", line 47, in <module>
     WordCount().run()
   File "site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 855, in run
   File "site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 504, in runTouchApp
   File "site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 747, in mainloop
   File "site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 479, in _mainloop
   File "site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 339, in idle
   File "site-packages\kivy\clock.py", line 591, in tick
   File "kivy\_clock.pyx", line 384, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events
   File "kivy\_clock.pyx", line 414, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events
   File "kivy\_clock.pyx", line 412, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events
   File "kivy\_clock.pyx", line 167, in kivy._clock.ClockEvent.tick
   File "site-packages\kivy\uix\filechooser.py", line 698, in _update_files
   File "site-packages\kivy\uix\filechooser.py", line 718, in _create_files_entries
   File "site-packages\kivy\uix\filechooser.py", line 839, in _generate_file_entries
   File "site-packages\kivy\uix\filechooser.py", line 871, in _add_files
   File "site-packages\kivy\uix\filechooser.py", line 871, in <listcomp>
   File "site-packages\kivy\uix\filechooser.py", line 178, in is_hidden
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32timezone'
[10576] Failed to execute script wordcount
```

**Moreover, I'm pretty sure this is just the beginning.** Is there any other solution?

Any help will be appreciated. I know these issues were discussed before, and I apologize in advance, but non of the solutions I found work for me.

PS: the list of "missing modules" in *warn.txt* is long as the Great Wall of China, is it normal? Especially considering that only two modules are in use.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I solved the issue, but the solution is not very elegant:

```
pyinstaller --add-data "./wordcount.kv;." --hiddenimport pkg_resources.py2_warn --hiddenimport win32timezone --hiddenimport textract.parsers.pptx_parser --hiddenimport textract.parsers.docx_parser wordcount.py
```

Then I copied *libpng16-16.dll* from one of the Python folders to the /dist/ folder.

If somebody knows better way please share it...